# A future-oriented code upgrade. Avoid exiting the function if an error occurs

Tags: python, django, csv

I've to pass some data from incoming object, but I cannot be sure about the values that this object contains. Some(or each) of the object value may be defined or not. I'll not end the function with a lot of `try: except:` code. So here is my function that exports the data as `csv` file. And in case that one of the value of the incoming object undefined this code fails.

```
def export_data(output, queryset, dialect=csv.excel):
    writer = csv.writer(output, dialect=dialect)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Email', 'Tool', 'Location', 'Box', 'Booking timestamp',
                     'Checkout timestamp', 'Return timestamp', 'Loan costs incl. VAT', 'Loan costs excl. VAT',
                     'VAT percentage', 'Feedback overall rating', 'Feedback remarks'])
    for event in events:
        row = ["{} {}".format(event.userprofile.firstname, event.userprofile.lastname),
               event.userprofile.user.email,
               event.toolitem.tool.name,
               event.toolitem.box.location.name,
               event.toolitem.box.number,
               event.booking_ts,
               event.checkout_ts,
               event.return_ts]
        if event.state in (event.RETURNED, event.PAYED):
            row += [event.loan_costs,
                    (event.loan_costs / (event.vat_percentage / Decimal(100) + Decimal(1))
                     ).quantize(Decimal('.01')),
                    event.vat_percentage]
        else:
            row += ['', '', '']
        try:
            row += [event.feedback.get_overall_rating_display(), event.feedback.remarks]
        except:
            row += ['', '']
        writer.writerow(row)
    return output
```

This function should be more flexible and if a value does not exist, replace it with an empty string.

**Update**

I've endet up with following for loop, this is terrible o_O is there no "readable" way to do this?

```
for event in events:
    row = [
        "{} {}".format(
            event.userprofile.firstname if hasattr(event.userprofile, 'firstname') else '',
            event.userprofile.lastname if hasattr(event.userprofile, 'lastname') else ''),
        (event.userprofile.user.email if hasattr(event.userprofile.user, 'email') else '') if hasattr(
            event.userprofile, 'user') else '',
        event.toolitem.tool.name if event.toolitem.tool.name else '',
        event.toolitem.box.location.name if event.toolitem.box.location.name else '',
        event.toolitem.box.number if event.toolitem.box.number else '',
        event.booking_ts if event.booking_ts else '',
        event.checkout_ts if event.checkout_ts else '',
        event.return_ts if event.return_ts else '']
    if event.state in (event.RETURNED, event.PAYED):
        row += [event.loan_costs,
                (event.loan_costs / (event.vat_percentage / Decimal(100) + Decimal(1))
                 ).quantize(Decimal('.01')),
                event.vat_percentage]
    else:
        row += ['', '', '']
    try:
        row += [event.feedback.get_overall_rating_display(), event.feedback.remarks]
    except:
        row += ['', '']
    row += [(event.userprofile.user.date_joined.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") if hasattr(
                event.userprofile.user, 'date_joined') else '') if hasattr(event.userprofile, 'user') else '']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You can use "or" statement.
`a = variable or "Hello World"`will assign "Hello World" if `variable` is None.
You cloud also make usage of ternary coupled with `hasattr`/ `getattr`
`a = variable.stuf if hasattr(variable,"stuff") else ""`

Comment: in your approach I've to predefine the values, right? I mean, I've `row` array and here are the variables passed, should I first define them and then pass to array?